# My code is not working because i have to make these tables responsive on col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12

Tags: html, css

My code is not working properly on col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-lg please help me to make it responsive. Its not properly working . My responsive code is  not working it show same results in all screens.Default bootstrap classes is not working in it.How can i do it.instaed of using divs i have to work on tables.My code is not working properly on col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-lg please help me to make it responsive.

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <table class="responsive table">
        <tr class="container">
        <!-- child table 1 starts -->
            <td class="row responsive table">
                <table class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <tbody class="logo-box">
                        <tr class="table winning-nbr-box winning-nbr">
                            <td class="winning-logo text-center">
                                <a href="https://www.lotterycorner.com/oh/pick-3-midday">
                                    <img src="./Ohio (OH) Lottery Results - Latest Winning numbers_files/oh-pick3.png" alt="Ohio  Pick 3 Midday Winning numbers" style="margin-top:40px;">
                                </a>
                                <p class="winning-inner">
                                    <p class="sort-text" style="border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;">
                                        <h3 style="font-size: 23px; color: #000; font-weight: 700; text-align:justify; padding:2px 20px; margin-top:-18px;">
                                        Pick 3 Midday
                                        </h3>
                                        <p class="upper-c-text" style="text-align:justify; padding:2px 20px; margin-top:-1px; color:#616161; font-size:14px;">Wednesday, December 20, 2017 Winning Number</p>
                                        <ul class="nbr-grp">
                                            <li> 8 </li>
                                            <li> 7 </li>
                                            <li> 3 </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <span class="upper-c-text next" style="color:#616161;">
                                            <strong>Top Prize/ Jackpot</strong>
                                        </span>
                                        <br>
                                        <span class="current" style="color:#616161; font-size:20px;">$500</span>
                                        <p style="border:1px solid #ddd"></p>
                                        <p class="box-btm-part">
                                            <span style="color:#172d48;">Next Draw at : Thu, Dec-21-2017, 12:29 PM (US/Eastern )
                                            </span>
                                            <br>
                                            <span class="upper-c-text next" style="font-size:18px; line-height:24px;font-family: 'Neris-Light',sans-serif; color:#172d48;">
                                            <strong>Next Jackpot</strong>
                                            </span>
                                            <br>
                                            <span class="price next" style="color:#172d48; font-size:26px;">
                                                <strong>$500</strong>
                                            </span>
                                        </p>
                                        <p>
                                            <a href="https://www.lotterycorner.com/oh/pick-3-midday" class="result-btn">&nbsp;&#10095;&nbsp;&nbsp; Find Out More&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
                                        </p>
                                    </p>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>    
                </table>
            </td>
            <!-- child table 1 ends -->
            <!-- child table 2 starts -->
            <td class="row responsive table">
                <table class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <tbody class="logo-box">
                        <tr class="table winning-nbr-box winning-nbr">
                            <td class="winning-logo text-center">
                                <a href="https://www.lotterycorner.com/oh/pick-3-evening">
                                    <img src="./Ohio (OH) Lottery Results - Latest Winning numbers_files/oh-pick3.png" alt="Ohio  Pick 3 Evening Winning numbers" style="margin-top:40px;">
                                </a>
                                <p class="winning-inner">
                                    <p class="sort-text" style="border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;">
                                        <h3 style="font-size: 23px; color: #000; font-weight: 700; text-align:justify; padding:2px 20px; margin-top:-18px;">
                                            Pick 3 Evening
                                        </h3>
                                        <p class="upper-c-text" style="text-align:justify; padding:2px 20px; margin-top:-1px; color:#616161; font-size:14px;">Wednesday, December 20, 2017 Winning Number</p>
                                        <ul class="nbr-grp">
                                            <li> 1 </li>
                                            <li> 6 </li>
                                            <li> 6 </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <span class="upper-c-text next" style="color:#616161;">
                                            <strong>Top Prize/ Jackpot</strong>
                                        </span>
                                        <br>
                                        <span class="current" style="color:#616161; font-size:20px;">$500</span>
                                        <p style="border:1px solid #ddd"></p>
                                        <p class="box-btm-part">
                                            <span style="color:#172d48;">Next Draw at : Thu, Dec-21-2017, 07:29 PM (US/Eastern )
                                            </span>
                                            <br>
                                            <span class="upper-c-text next" style="font-size:18px; line-height:24px;font-family: 'Neris-Light',sans-serif; color:#172d48;">
                                                <strong>Next Jackpot</strong>
                                            </span>
                                            <br>
                                            <span class="price next" style="color:#172d48; font-size:26px;">
                                                <strong>$500</strong>
                                            </span>
                                        </p>
                                        <p>
                                            <a href="https://www.lotterycorner.com/oh/pick-3-evening" class="result-btn">&nbsp;&#10095;&nbsp;&nbsp; Find Out More&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
                                        </p>
                                    </p>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <!-- child table 2 ends -->
            <!-- child table 3 starts -->
            <td class="row responsive table">
                <table class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <tbody class="logo-box">
                        <tr class="table winning-nbr-box winning-nbr">
                            <td class="winning-logo text-center">
                                <a href="https://www.lotterycorner.com/oh/pick-4-midday">
                                    <img src="./Ohio (OH) Lottery Results - Latest Winning numbers_files/oh-pick4.png" alt="Ohio  Pick 4 Midday Winning numbers" style="margin-top:40px;">
                                </a>
                                <p class="winning-inner">
                                    <p class="sort-text" style="border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;">
                                        <h3 style="font-size: 23px; color: #000; font-weight: 700; text-align:justify; padding:2px 20px; margin-top:-18px;">
                                            Pick 4 Midday
                                        </h3>
                                        <p class="upper-c-text" style="text-align:justify; padding:2px 20px; margin-top:-1px; color:#616161; font-size:14px;">Wednesday, December 20, 2017 Winning Number</p>
                                        <ul class="nbr-grp">
                                            <li> 6 </li>
                                            <li> 1 </li>
                                            <li> 3 </li>
                                            <li> 5 </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <span class="upper-c-text next" style="color:#616161;">
                                            <strong>Top Prize/ Jackpot</strong>
                                        </span>
                                        <br>
                                        <span class="current" style="color:#616161; font-size:20px;">$500</span>
                                        <p style="border:1px solid #ddd"></p>
                                        <p class="box-btm-part">
                                            <span style="color:#172d48;">Next Draw at : Thu, Dec-21-2017, 12:29 PM (US/Eastern )
                                            </span>
                                            <br>
                                            <span class="upper-c-text next" style="font-size:18px; line-height:24px;font-family: 'Neris-Light',sans-serif; color:#172d48;">
                                                <strong>Next Jackpot</strong>
                                            </span>
                                            <br>
                                            <span class="price next" style="color:#172d48; font-size:26px;">
                                                <strong>$5,000</strong>
                                            </span>
                                        </p>
                                        <p>
                                            <a href="https://www.lotterycorner.com/oh/pick-4-midday" class="result-btn">&nbsp;&#10095;&nbsp;&nbsp; Find Out More&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
                                        </p>
                                    </p>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <!--child table3 ends-->
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your "responsive code"? What are you trying to achieve? What is actually happening?

Answer (score 0):

In [Official Bootstrap Website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables-responsive) at tables section exactly, they have said:

> ## Responsive tables
>
> Create responsive tables by wrapping any `.table` in `.table-responsive` to make them scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, you will not see any difference in these tables.

Hence there is no class called `.responsive.table`,

also there is no need to use grid utilities to achieve responsive bootstrap table just wrap the table with a container that holds `.table-responsive` and remove `.row`, `.col` classes then it should be responsive.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table text-center">
        <tr class="container">
            <!-- child table 1 starts -->
            <td class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody class="logo-box">
                        <tr class="table winning-nbr-box winning-nbr">

                            <td class="winning-logo text-center">
                                <a href="https://www.lotterycorner.com/oh/pick-3-midday">
                                        <img src="./Ohio (OH) Lottery Results - Latest Winning numbers_files/oh-pick3.png" alt="Ohio  Pick 3 Midday Winning numbers"
                                            style="margin-top:40px;">
                                    </a>
                                <p class="winning-inner">
                                    <p class="sort-text" style="border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;">
                                        <h3 style="font-size: 23px; color: #000; font-weight: 700; text-align:justify; padding:2px 20px; margin-top:-18px;">
                                            Pick 3 Midday
                                        </h3>
                                        <p class="upper-c-text" style="text-align:justify; padding:2px 20px; margin-top:-1px; color:#616161; font-size:14px;">Wednesday, December 20, 2017 Winning Number</p>

                                        <ul class="nbr-grp">
                                            <li> 8 </li>
                                            <li> 7 </li>
                                            <li> 3 </li>
                                        </ul>


                                        <span class="upper-c-text next" style="color:#616161;">
                                                <strong>Top Prize/ Jackpot</strong>
                                            </span>
                                        <br>
                                        <span class="current" style="color:#616161; font-size:20px;">$500</span>
                                        <p style="border:1px solid #ddd"></p>
                                        <p class="box-btm-part">
                                            <span style="color:#172d48;">Next Draw at : Thu, Dec-21-2017, 12:29 PM (US/Eastern )
                                                </span>
                                            <br>

                                            <span class="upper-c-text next" style="font-size:18px; line-height:24px;font-family: 'Neris-Light',sans-serif; color:#172d48;">
                                                    <strong>Next Jackpot</strong>
                                                </span>
                                            <br>
                                            <span class="price next" style="color:#172d48; font-size:26px;">
                                                    <strong>$500</strong>
                                                </span>
                                        </p>
                                        <p>
                                            <a href="https://www.lotterycorner.com/oh/pick-3-midday" class="result-btn">&nbsp;&#10095;&nbsp;&nbsp; Find Out More&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
                                        </p>
                            </td>



                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <!-- child table 1 ends -->
            <!-- child table 2 starts -->
            <td class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody class="logo-box">
                        <tr class="table winning-nbr-box winning-nbr">
                            <td class="winning-logo text-center">
                                <a href="https://www.lotterycorner.com/oh/pick-3-evening">
                                        <img src="./Ohio (OH) Lottery Results - Latest Winning numbers_files/oh-pick3.png" alt="Ohio  Pick 3 Evening Winning numbers"
                                            style="margin-top:40px;">
                                    </a>
                                <p class="winning-inner">
                                    <p class="sort-text" style="border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;">
                                        <h3 style="font-size: 23px; color: #000; font-weight: 700; text-align:justify; padding:2px 20px; margin-top:-18px;">
                                            Pick 3 Evening
                                        </h3>
                                        <p class="upper-c-text" style="text-align:justify; padding:2px 20px; margin-top:-1px; color:#616161; font-size:14px;">Wednesday, December 20, 2017 Winning Number</p>

                                        <ul class="nbr-grp">
                                            <li> 1 </li>
                                            <li> 6 </li>
                                            <li> 6 </li>
                                        </ul>


                                        <span class="upper-c-text next" style="color:#616161;">
                                                <strong>Top Prize/ Jackpot</strong>
                                            </span>
                                        <br>
                                        <span class="current" style="color:#616161; font-size:20px;">$500</span>
                                        <p style="border:1px solid #ddd"></p>
                                        <p class="box-btm-part">
                                            <span style="color:#172d48;">Next Draw at : Thu, Dec-21-2017, 07:29 PM (US/Eastern )
                                                </span>
                                            <br>

                                            <span class="upper-c-text next" style="font-size:18px; line-height:24px;font-family: 'Neris-Light',sans-serif; color:#172d48;">
                                                    <strong>Next Jackpot</strong>
                                                </span>
                                            <br>
                                            <span class="price next" style="color:#172d48; font-size:26px;">
                                                    <strong>$500</strong>
                                                </span>
                                        </p>
                                        <p>
                                            <a href="https://www.lotterycorner.com/oh/pick-3-evening" class="result-btn">&nbsp;&#10095;&nbsp;&nbsp; Find Out More&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
                                        </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <!-- child table 2 ends -->
            <!-- child table 3 starts -->
            <td class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody class="logo-box">
                        <tr class="table winning-nbr-box winning-nbr">
                            <td class="winning-logo text-center">
                                <a href="https://www.lotterycorner.com/oh/pick-4-midday">
                                        <img src="./Ohio (OH) Lottery Results - Latest Winning numbers_files/oh-pick4.png" alt="Ohio  Pick 4 Midday Winning numbers"
                                            style="margin-top:40px;">
                                    </a>
                                <p class="winning-inner">
                                    <p class="sort-text" style="border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;">
                                        <h3 style="font-size: 23px; color: #000; font-weight: 700; text-align:justify; padding:2px 20px; margin-top:-18px;">
                                            Pick 4 Midday
                                        </h3>
                                        <p class="upper-c-text" style="text-align:justify; padding:2px 20px; margin-top:-1px; color:#616161; font-size:14px;">Wednesday, December 20, 2017 Winning Number</p>
                                        <ul class="nbr-grp">
                                            <li> 6 </li>
                                            <li> 1 </li>
                                            <li> 3 </li>
                                            <li> 5 </li>
                                        </ul>


                                        <span class="upper-c-text next" style="color:#616161;">
                                                <strong>Top Prize/ Jackpot</strong>
                                            </span>
                                        <br>
                                        <span class="current" style="color:#616161; font-size:20px;">$500</span>
                                        <p style="border:1px solid #ddd"></p>
                                        <p class="box-btm-part">
                                            <span style="color:#172d48;">Next Draw at : Thu, Dec-21-2017, 12:29 PM (US/Eastern )
                                                </span>
                                            <br>

                                            <span class="upper-c-text next" style="font-size:18px; line-height:24px;font-family: 'Neris-Light',sans-serif; color:#172d48;">
                                                    <strong>Next Jackpot</strong>
                                                </span>
                                            <br>
                                            <span class="price next" style="color:#172d48; font-size:26px;">
                                                    <strong>$5,000</strong>
                                                </span>
                                        </p>
                                        <p>
                                            <a href="https://www.lotterycorner.com/oh/pick-4-midday" class="result-btn">&nbsp;&#10095;&nbsp;&nbsp; Find Out More&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
                                        </p>
                            </td>



                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <!--child table3 ends-->
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```